# Spring Source Tool Suite (equals Eclipse IDE ) javascript "Open Declaration" Not Possible

Tags: javascript, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I work on a Grails Web Project with Spring Source Tool Suite 2.9.0 ( This IDE is build on Eclipse and looks the same, you can install even the eclipse plugins )

I have in the Project folder "MyProject" a "JS" subfolder which contains JavaScript ( .js ) files.

When I try to open the declaration of a javascript function by rightclicking on the call and selecting "Open Declaration F3" I get the Error "the resource is not on the build path of a javascript project"

Is there a way to manage that I can follow the Function call and definition 
( I would try even a Eclipse Plugin )

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you check the Eclipse project specific files into SVN. 
These files tell Eclipse what type of project it is working with. They also maintain things like `classpaths` and `dependencies`.

The files will include `.project` and `.classpath` for a Java project. If you didn't add these files to SVN, then Eclipse won't know how to handle the project when you check it out.

Comment: I opened the whole Workspace in My Windows User from another user so the .project and .class path files are the ones the project was build with